# Is there a word for the "visual part" that hides the agenda?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I think I read somewhere that "hidden agenda" has two parts. The part that's visible, and the agenda (which is hidden by the visible). Is there a term or word for the visible part of a hidden agenda?

Comment: The visible part that hides the 'hidden agenda' is called - 'the agenda'. Welcome to EL&U.

Comment: The visible part would be the 'published agenda' if there was a formal agenda, however many _hidden agendas_ are completely concealed to the extent that the actions being taken or proposed don't even seem to be part of a plan. This doesn't mean that I believe in secret conspiracies, most people I've heard being accused of conspiracy couldn't conspire their way out of a paper bag!

Comment: Are you looking for "optics"?

Comment: The *"smokescreen"*.

Answer (score 5):

The pretext.

> **pretext**  *NOUN*
>
> a reason given in justification of a course of action that is not the real reason.

Comment: Great answer, it would be improved with a citation for your definition (and beginning a line with a >  will format that line as a yellow quote box)

Answer (score 0):

You could say someone had an agenda which consisted of both a hidden agenda and an overt agenda.

Answer (score 0):

The "visible part" that is hiding the hidden agenda is a ***front***.

ODO:

> **[front](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/front)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **3** [*in singular*] An appearance or form of behaviour assumed by a person
>   to conceal their genuine feelings.
>
> ‘she put on a brave front’
>
> ‘Some people can put up a front and pretend to be someone they are
>   not.’

Answer (score 0):

Cambridge Dictionaries defines [***ostensible***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ostensible) as:

> appearing or claiming to be one thing when it is really something else

In your case then there is the *ostensible* agenda and the *hidden* agenda.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything about *hidden agenda* that implies a visible part. But you might need to provide some explanation for actions taken in pursuit of said agenda on a case by case basis. In which case you need **cover**.

> 3
>    a : something that conceals or obscures under cover of darkness
>   b : a masking device : pretext The project was a cover for intelligence operations.

"Cover." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 22 Jan. 2018.